# cannot find my package in apt-get

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I programmed my own ros package and did all the steps described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation) to share it. The package is even built on the [farm](http://jenkins.ros.org/job/doc-groovy-text_locator/). Still, when I do sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-te [tab] the auto complete does not offer my package. What have I done wrong?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79126/cannot-find-my-package-in-apt-get/) by [vonovak](https://answers.ros.org/users/4872/vonovak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This only indexes your package for the documentation. You should be able to find the entry in the wiki.

To get it via apt-get you need to release your package: http://wiki.ros.org/bloom

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1